# Packaging an Sqlite DB in my Codename One Application

Tags: codenameone

I have created an sqlite db as part of my mobile app. The db currently resides in /home/stevenmark/.cn1/database. The application works when I run it in the IDE using the emulator.

But I cannot see it in the SourcePackages/< default packages > Project tree structure -- all I can see there is 'theme.res' ( I'm using NetBeans )

Now I want to package my app and use it on my device. How do I make sure that my DB comes along and installs itself properly when I install the app on the actual device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff in the `.cn1` directory is your debug data it doesn't ship with your app. If you have a specific database you want to ship with the app you can place that file under the src directory (directly under not in a sub folder).

The [SQL section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql) in the developer guide specifically talks about shipping an app with a pre-existing database:

> Some SQLite apps ship with a "ready made" database. We allow you to replace the DB file by using the code:
>
> ```
> String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath(“databaseName”);
> ```
>
> You can then use the FileSystemStorage class to write the content of your DB file into the path. Notice that it must be a valid SQLite file!

Comment: Thanks Shai -- may I follow up with a related question? In the past when I tried to package the db with my app, I would execute an insert query and get an error along the lines of ' no such database ' -- which is how I knew that the db was not being installed as a part of the app. But now - following your advice, I am no longer getting this error --- so I assume that the db exits. However when I try and run an select I get no response -- no error either -- just nothing. Is there a way to locate the db and browse it - or is there another way to tell if it is present and being populated?

Comment: Did you look at the SQLDemo/DBExplorer? It shows how to ship a database with the app and also how to let you run an arbitrary SQL statement on that database. FYI Normally stackoverflow is better suited for new questions rather than extensive followups in comment sections.